# delete only parent element jquery

Tags: jquery

i have 3 box with same name, if i click `.fonarcom` jquery hide all  .pagamento`.

There is a way to hide only the `.pagamento` within the parent container?

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(".fonarcom").click(function() {
    if (j(this).is(':checked')) {
        j(".pagamento").hide();
    } else {
        j(".pagamento").show();
    };
});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="large-6 columns ">
    <label><input name="fonarcom" class="fonarcom" type="checkbox" value="SI"> L'azienda aderisce a FonarCom</label>
</div>


<div class="large-6 columns pagamento">
    <label>Modalità di pagamento</label>
    <select name="pagamento" required>
    <option value="">Seleziona un metodo di pagamento</option>
    <option value="Contanti/Assegno Inizio Corso">Contanti/Assegno Inizio Corso</option>
    <option value="Bonifico Anticipato">Bonifico Anticipato</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The HTML you posted does not give any hints on what `pagament` you wanna hide and which you wanna show.

Comment: If the div with the class pagamento is only one element then hiding it will hide/show it for all inputs.  From your code sample, it appears to be only one element. Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you need *the parent container*, so i made a div wrapper (but i suppose you already have one)

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="large-6 columns ">
      <label><input name="fonarcom" class="fonarcom" type="checkbox" value="SI"> L'azienda aderisce a FonarCom</label>
   </div>

   <div class="large-6 columns pagamento">
      <label>Modalità di pagamento</label>
      <select name="pagamento" required>
         <option value="">Seleziona un metodo di pagamento</option>
         <option value="Contanti/Assegno Inizio Corso">Contanti/Assegno Inizio Corso</option>
         <option value="Bonifico Anticipato">Bonifico Anticipato</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
       <div class="large-6 columns ">
           ...
```

then in jQuery just select the container and find the correct *.pagamento*

```
if( j(this).is(':checked') ) {
   j(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".pagamento").hide();
} else {
   j(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".pagamento").show();  
};
```

See the working example here: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/puLzs5mz/)

Answer (score 0):

As `pagamento` is sibling of `fonarcom`'s parent `div` element. You can use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to `div`, then use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to  find immediate following sibling.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(".fonarcom").click(function() {
    j(this).closest('div').next(".pagamento").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Here, I have use [`.toggle(display)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)

> Use `true` to show the element or `false` to hide it.